# How to check the value of a single pixel in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I was wondering how to check the value of a pixel at a mouse click in QGIS (as of 2.4).

In ArcGIS, the **Identify** tool does the job for both rasters and vectors. However, in QGIS, the **Identify** tool seems to be greyed out when only one raster layer is loaded.

Comment: Even if there is only one layer, you have to select it in the TOC to activate the identify tool.

Comment: That's kind of unintuitive. But thanks though. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In QGIS v.2.6.1, I can effectively use the Identify tool to get values from each raster band on a mouse click.

Additionally (and if you are using other QGIS versions), you could use the [Value Tool plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/valuetool/), which displays raster band values (and even a graph) on mouse movement.

Comment: Thanks! I just upgraded to QGIS 2.6.1, and it works as suggested.